# How do you calculate the best/worst case complexity of an algorithm?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computational-complexity, analysis-of-algorithms

I have been given the example:

ALGORITHM 1:
Require: $n \ge 0 $
$x \leftarrow  1$
$\;\;\;\;\;\;$for $i = 1$   to $n$ do:
$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$$x \leftarrow x \cdot i$
$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ $i \leftarrow i + 1$
$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$end for

And the time complexity is given by $T(n) = 4n+2$. I understand this to mean that there are 2 assignment statements (hence $+ 2$), and the loop is executed n times, which consists of two assignment statements, as well as two arithmetic operations, giving 4 total operations for each loop (hence $4n$). How do I then go on to find the best and worst case complexity of such an algorithm?

I am now looking at a more complicated algorithm

ALGORITHM 2:
Require: $i \leftarrow 2$
while $i \le \;$ length$(A)$ do
$\;\;\;\;\; j \leftarrow i$
$\;\;\;\;$ while $j >0$ and $A[j-1] > A[j]$ do
$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$swap$(A[j], A[j-1])$
$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;j \leftarrow j-1$
$\;\;\;\;$end while
$\;\;\;\;i \leftarrow i + 1$
end while

In this case, I'm really not sure how to calculate $T(n)$, nor the best/worst case complexity. As far as I can go is to identify that there is 1 initial assignment statement. After that, I get lost looking at all the while loops. Could someone help me understand how to calculate $T(n)$, and the best/worst case complexities? All advice appreciated!

Comment: Have you encountered the big-O notation $\mathcal{O}(n)$? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: The 2nd algorithm is $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ order.

Comment: I have. Does $\mathcal{O}(n^{2})$ mean that the worst time complexity does not exceed $n^{2}$? If that is the case, how do you know this by looking at the algorithm?

Comment: As $n$ approaches infinity, the constants will be insignificant, so that's the worst time complexity you can get for any $n$. By simply looking at the how many loop within a loop, you will see that it is of that order. In algorithm 1, you only have 1 loop so $\mathcal{O}(n)$ while in the second, you have an inner $n$-computation loop inside the outer loop with $n$-times so $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$.